# How to add one day to all DateTime columns in a database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a server which hosts my application. The application is working. Yesterday I realized that the server date is one day behind.

How can I change the server date as well as update all my `DateTime` columns in my database by adding one day to each record?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run this SQL statement:

```
select 'update '+so.name+' set '+sc.name+' = dateadd(day,1,'+sc.name+')'
from sysobjects so
inner join syscolumns sc 
on so.id = sc.id
where sc.xtype = 61
and so.type = 'u'
```

And copy the results and paste them into the Query Window and execute.

```
update Status set CreatedDate = dateadd(day,1,CreatedDate)
update Status set DateUpdated = dateadd(day,1,DateUpdated)
update TxSession set SessionDate = dateadd(day,1,SessionDate)
update TxSession set CreatedDate = dateadd(day,1,CreatedDate)
update TxSession set LastModifiedDate = dateadd(day,1,LastModifiedDate)
```

Comment: But I don't recommend such a heavy handed approach.  I'd be surprised if EVERY field in your DB was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference the top things to remember when writing dynamic SQL to do this type of work are:

- Always include your schema.  You don't know that all of the objects are dbo.
- Even more important always put []'s around the names.  I've had to many cases my dynamic SQL died because the name of the table started with a number or symbol.

I know I used a cursor (bad Ken, bad) but in this case it seemed appropriate.  Of course you could just run the query and copy and paste the output to a new query window.  Might even be easier that way.

```
DECLARE UpdateCur
FOR 
    SELECT 'UPDATE ['+tabs.TABLE_SCHEMA+'].['+tabs.TABLE_NAME+'] ' + 
        'SET ['+cols.COLUMN_NAME+'] = DATEADD(dd,1,['+cols.COLUMN_NAME+']);'
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS cols
    JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES tabs
        ON cols.TABLE_NAME = tabs.TABLE_NAME
    WHERE tabs.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' -- Exclude views
    -- Include datatypes DATE, DATETIME, DATETIME2, DATETIMEOFFSET
      AND cols.DATA_TYPE LIKE 'DATE%' 


DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
OPEN UpdateCur

FETCH NEXT FROM UpdateCur INTO @sql
WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
BEGIN
    IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_executeSQL @sql
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM UpdateCur INTO @sql
END

CLOSE UpdateCur
DEALLOCATE UpdateCur
GO
```